# Is there a way to co-deploy a set of stateless services on a given node in service fabric cluster?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

Here is the scenario:

1. I have stateless services A, B, C and D.
2. I want to deploy the above services into a 5 node service fabric cluster.
3. I would like to have only 3 instances of each service. (I know how to do this).
4. I need to deploy service A and C together always on a given node. (Sidecar pattern).
5. I don't care about which particular node can have both A and C, just that they need to be together.

*Is there a way to do this in service fabric cluster? If so, how? Once automated, I don't want to think about it afterwords knowing that they would always deploy together. Yet, I should be able to deploy either A or C independently.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [service affinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-advanced-placement-rules-affinity#how-to-configure-affinity).

Here is a quote from documentation:

> You can think of affinity as “pointing” one service at another and saying “This service can only run where that service is running.” Sometimes we refer to affinity as a parent/child relationship (where you point the child at the parent). Affinity ensures that the replicas or instances of one service are placed on the same nodes as those of another service.

Comment: It appears that NonAlignedAffinity solves my issues. Thanks.